# Why does Asyncio's event loop do more iterations than expected?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop

I am trying to understand how the `asyncio` event loop knows that it must do "N" iterations. So first I looked for a way to determine the number of iterations it does. For that, I downloaded the Cpython source code (`V3.11.4`) and I added a new attribute for `BaseEventLoop` class named `self._loop_iterations` and I set it to `0`, then I incremented it by 1 in the `def _run_once(self)`, it was something like this:

```py
#cpython/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py

class BaseEventLoop(events.AbstractEventLoop):

    def __init__(self):
        ....
        # loop iterations
        self._loop_iterations = 0

    def _run_once(self):
        """Run one full iteration of the event loop.

        This calls all currently ready callbacks, polls for I/O,
        schedules the resulting callbacks, and finally schedules
        'call_later' callbacks.
        """
        self._loop_iterations += 1
        ...
```

after compiling I used the updated cpython version to run the above code which printed `loop iteration: 4`

```py
#loop_iterations.py

import asyncio


async def coro(msg):
    print(">>> running coro <<<")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(">>> finished coro <<<")
    return msg


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(coro("Andres"))
print("loop iterations: ", loop._loop_iterations)
```

why did the previous code print 4 ?

according to my understanding it should print 2 iterations because it would do something like this:

- first iteration: run `coro` until it hits the await statement.
- second iteration: when `coro` wakes up after sleeping for 2 secs, the event loop iterates again and it resumes coro and it set its return value `msg`, and then stops.

What's wrong with my understanding? am I leaving out an internal process of the event loop?

Comment: I will likely tackle your question later - just leaving this side note: no need to re-build Python from source for hacks like this (nice one): for changing code in Python files, just find the ".py" file used in your environment, and edit that one directly. `import asyncio; print(asyncio.__file__)` will show you the full path to the file. 
You can just use an ad-hoc git on the library dir and version only your hacked files, if you want to be able to go back and forth your modified versions.

Answer (score 1):

So, the real thing is that the actual number of iterations of the async loop does not matter, and it is an implementation detail.

So much that even the `_run_once` method you modified is marked as private, as it is an implementation detail. The thing asserted in cases like this is that the tasks will run to completion.

The implementation of Python's asyncio default loop is itself complex - probably it can't be made much simpler, and simple things as "warming up", and "ensure there is nothing pending" could account for the extra iterations.

It is alright to test and check things like you are doing to better understand their inner workings: for example, you could extend your test to check if there are always just "2 extra iterations" above the ones you were expecting, or if that number grows with the number of tasks somehow - but always keep in mind that number is just an implementation detail that should affect no outcome of "real" code. Keep in mind that, as an implementation detail, this could change overnight, even in a micro-release of Python.  (Just as the method `_run_once` itself could even cease to exist - no code should depend on it)

Asyncio is known to be easy to be "stopped in the wrong way", with pending tasks not yet executed. Researching the best practices so that your code never falls into that situation is a good thing. Since Python 3.11, the `asyncio.TaskGroup` had been added to help coding patterns where that is easier to accomplish.

All that said, going back to your question - the mechanism to *stop* the loop used by `run_until_complete`  (And, by `asyncio.run`), is to add a callback to the passed in future, so that when it is done, the current loop `.stop()` method is called. This sets the internal `._stopping` attribute, which, when checked at the `run_forever` method stops calling `_run_once` in a repeated way.

Python asyncio.base_events.py:

```
...

def _run_until_complete_cb(fut):
    if not fut.cancelled():
        ...
    futures._get_loop(fut).stop()

...

class BaseEventLoop(...):
    
    ...

    def run_forever(self):
        """Run until stop() is called."""
        try:
            self._run_forever_setup()
            while True:
                self._run_once()
                if self._stopping:
                    break
        finally:
            self._run_forever_cleanup()
    ...

    def run_until_complete(self, future):
        """Run until the Future is done.

        ...
        """
        ...
        future.add_done_callback(_run_until_complete_cb)
        try:
            self.run_forever()    # <- this is just stopped because the `done callback` above does so.
        except:
            ...
        
        return future.result()
    
    ...
    def stop(self):
        """Stop running the event loop.

        Every callback already scheduled will still run.  This simply informs
        run_forever to stop looping after a complete iteration.
        """
        self._stopping = True
```

If future callbacks were run synchronously: i.e. just called like ordinary functions like what takes place in synchronous code (for example, in plain, sync, Python, the `__del__` method of an object is called synchronously as an object looses its last reference), that would mean `_run_once` would not be called again after the main future was not accomplished. But as you can see in `asyncio/futures.py` file, future done callbacks are scheduled and called *on the next pass* of the event loop: only then will `loop.stop()` be called: so at least one extra pass of `_run_once` is caused by this.

Python asyncio.futures.py:

```
... 
    class Future:

    ...

    def __schedule_callbacks(self):
        """Internal: Ask the event loop to call all callbacks.

        The callbacks are scheduled to be called as soon as possible. Also
        clears the callback list.
        """
        callbacks = self._callbacks[:]
        if not callbacks:
            return

        self._callbacks[:] = []
        for callback, ctx in callbacks:
            self._loop.call_soon(callback, self, context=ctx)
```

If the other extra pass is due to some other delay in this, or something that takes place at the `run_forever` setup, you can check - but it is both related to these mechanisms, and irrelevant to actual asyncio using code, as I said above.

Comment: I think that the event loop iterations can matter because, this is resource-consuming, If such impact can be reduced, the better.

Comment: I added more tasks (all of them sleeping for the same amount (3s)) and there are always 4 iterations. Now, if the coroutine run by `run_until_complete` (from now on `ruc`) sleeps more than the previously added tasks, the number of iterations is 6, In the case of this coroutine sleeps less, the number of iterations is 4 again. Another check I did was to make some tasks sleep more than the coroutine run by  `ruc`, the iterations are 4 again, and the same happens when all the previously added tasks sleep more than the coroutine run by `ruc`. That's interesting!.